# What are the fusion rules of E-series minimal models?

Tags: conformal-field-theory

[Virasoro minimal models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_model_(physics)) are supposed to be solved, which is certainly true in the A-series and D-series, but the E-series models are more exotic. Do we at least know the (non-chiral) fusion rules? The more explicit the answer, the better!